# how to set footer in mobile site

Tags: css, html4

I have set the footer in mobile site but problem is when i scroll first time of the page that time my footer also scrolling after it fixed in bottom position this problem coming some phone and some phone working fine.

**EDITED**

I had attached the screenshot for your reference.

[image: FOOTER IMAGE]

Comment: position fixed is not supported on all mobile devices. besides, it tends to take up too much room on the mobile and is better set to position relative with media queries.

Comment: @CarolMcKay If i set the position as relative then the footer gets visible only after the end of scrolling but i need the footer at first time of loading and it should not get disappear even how many scrolls i do

Answer (score 0):

Fix your footer to the bottom using:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

And then add a width if you want.